# how to change variables for specific fundamental-mode buffers

Tags: emacs, advising-functions, defadvice

Goal: I want to have `show-trailing-whitespace` enabled for all buffers save a few. Exceptions posing a problem are `*Shell Command Output*` and its cousin `*Async Shell Command*`.

I usually have `show-trailing-whitespace` customized to `t`. Therefore it is active in all new buffers.

I would also like to have it turned off for certain buffers, foremost amongst them `*Shell Command Output*`. This poses a problem for me:

- The output buffer doesn't use a special mode; it is still in `fundamental-mode`. There is no `fundamental-mode-hook` that I could hook this setting into.
- There is the `after-major-mode-change-hook` which is run when the major mode is changed to `fundamental-mode`, but the buffer starts out in that mode and therefore this hook is not run.
- There doesn't seem to be a way to hook into `get-buffer-create`.

I know I can always `advise` the function `get-buffer-create` for this particular example, but I try to avoid that as much as possible.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off looking at the problem from the other side, and only set the var in those modes where you want to see trailing whitespace.

But I think you have a good point: these shell output buffers should not use `fundamental-mode`.  It's probably time for `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: I know, but until today those "other modes" were pretty much "all modes". Hence my preference not having to add a gazillion of hooks.

Comment: `prog-mode-hook` and `text-mode-hook` should cover a good proportion of those modes.

Comment: Good point, especially as I didn't know about that generic `prog-mode-hook`. I think I'll go that route; definitely preferable to using `advise`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with the accepted answer, here's a code snippet that enables trailing whitespaces highlighting for specific modes only:

```lisp
(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace nil)

(defun namespace/show-trailing-whitespace ()
  "Highlight trailing whitespaces in this buffer."
  (setq-local show-trailing-whitespace t))

(dolist (hook '(prog-mode-hook text-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook 'namespace/show-trailing-whitespace))
```

This snippet is essentially taken from [Steve Purcell's configuration](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-whitespace.el).